# In entropy change of surroundings, what is T?

Tags: energy, entropy

This question is simpler than the previous one about intuition of entropy; I just need to know whether the $T$ term in $dS_{Surr} = \frac{-dH}{T}$ refers to the temperature of the surroundings or the system. I think it needs to be both, no? For example, for water to boil, the system must have $T \geq$ 100 degrees C. But can it be said that at high temperatures the decrease in entropy of the surroundings due to endothermicity of the boiling reaction is less significant than at low temperatures, as per division by T, so at high temperatures of the surroundings boiling occurs spontaneously?

It seems like both explain the phenomenon, especially since boiling occurs over time in both a sample of water at 110 degrees C in a 32 degrees C environment until it cools and boiling eventually occurs in a 110 degree C furnace if the temperature of the water starts at 32 degrees C.

Comment: dS_Surr means how the surroundings' entropy changes due to the energy released/absorbed by the system, so I think it means the temperature of the surroundings.